# Receiving a KeyError when getting values from csv files

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve values from multiple csv files that are located in a directory. When performing `if row['opponent-points-per-game-rank'] == 6:` I am getting a Key Error. When I do something like:

```
if 'opponent-points-per-game-rank' in myfilereader.fieldnames:
    testrank = [row.get('opponent-points-per-game-rank') for row in myfilereader]
```

It will find the column name. Any reason why it can find the column name this way but not the other? Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D4aEqJogIt_typdgRHLNJhfWI-Os8iLI/view?usp=sharing) to my csv file. My code right now:

```
import os
import csv

testrank = []

 
directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Users\sm\OneDrive\TestProject") 

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
           myfilereader = csv.DictReader(f)
           for row in myfilereader:
               if row['opponent-points-per-game-rank'] == 6:
                  testrank.append(row['Team'])
           f.close() 

print(testrank)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure that `row` is an OrderedDict object. Here is my solution. Notice that you need to cast `v` to int because it is str.

```
import os
import csv

testrank = []

 
directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Users\sm\OneDrive\TestProject") 

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
           myfilereader = csv.DictReader(f)
           for row in myfilereader:
               for k,v in row.items():
               if k == 'opponent-points-per-game-rank' and int(v) == 6:
                  testrank.append(row['Team'])
           f.close() 

print(testrank)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce this issue using the file you linked, but I am not getting any errors. However, the value of `row['opponent-points-per-game-rank']` is a string, so `row['opponent-points-per-game-rank'] == 6` always evaluates to `False`. When this condition is replaced by `int(row['opponent-points-per-game-rank']) == 6` everything seems to work fine.

Comment: I concur.  I was going to say the same thing.  I get a line for each number from 1-357, and then a line with `[]` if I don't put quotes around the `6`, and `['Princeton']` if I do. - you're potentially reading other files that we don't have since you do a search for any file with a `.csv` extension.  Could it be that you are reading a different file that doesn't have that column in it?

Comment: Ok that might be the reason because even after I added the int(), I was still getting the KeyError. However when I applied it to that single file it worked. In theory though, wouldn't this script go down the list of each csv file and search for the the parameter in each column heading? @cryptoFool and bb1